# C# Rectangles intersection returns unexpected result

Tags: c#

The constructor documentation states that

> Rectangle(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)     Initializes a new instance of
>   the Rectangle class with the specified location and size.

Where:

> Parameters
>
> x
>
> Int32  The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle.
>
> y
>
> Int32  The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle.
>
> width
>
> Int32  The width of the rectangle.
>
> height
>
> Int32 The height of the rectangle.

With that in mind here's my couple of testing rectangles:

Rectangle1(25,43,11,9)

Rectangle2(35, 45, 9, 1)

As per MS documentation both x and y coordinates relate to the

> upper-left corner

, that is:

Rectangles1 x coordinate goes from 25 to 36 and y goes from 43 down to 34

Rectangles2 x coordinate goes from 35 to 44 and y goes from 45 down to 44

That means they do not overlap, as Rectangle2 base (y = 44) is 1 unit above Rectangle1 top (y = 43)

As a matter of fact that conflicts with following simple test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(25,43,11,9);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(35, 45, 9, 1);

        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle();
        r3 =  Rectangle.Intersect(r1, r2);

        if (!r3.IsEmpty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X = "+ r3.X);
            Console.WriteLine("Y = " + r3.Y);
            Console.WriteLine("Width = " + r3.Width);
            Console.WriteLine("Height = " + r3.Height);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("r1 and r2 do not intersect");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: Console output]

I am quite confused now, as testing rectangles result to overlap at coordinate 35,45 for a unit. Which I can't explain.

Comment: If `r1.x = 25` and its `r1.height = 11` then obviously `r2` with `x = 35` intersect with `r1` (since 25 + 11 > 35)

Comment: "y goes from 43 down to 34".  No, it goes *up* from 43 to 52.  This kind of confusion tends to be caused by the coordinate system used to do graphics, (0, 0) is in the upper-left corner.  Which makes it look like rectangles grow downwards.  There is a lot of hardware history behind that seemingly wonky choice, goes back to the way the electron beam traversed the screen in cathode ray tubes.

Comment: @HansPassant Now, that is REALLY weird. Are you saying that MS documentation says upper-left corner meaning lower-left ? That would be totally crazy. I am building an entire application on rectangles struct: should I trust anything else from MS official documentation ? Can you please confirm official documentation is saying "upper-left" for "lower-left"  ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that didn't help much, did it?  You'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Upper left is upper left. But 1 is a 'higher' (not larger!) number than 2 in the coordinate system. Think of it as line numbers

Answer (score 2):

It would seem, you are getting the y-axis wrong. R1 goes from 25, 43 to 35, 51, R2 goes from 35, 45 to 43, 45. My values are now INCLUSIVE bound, therefore it is x + width - 1 and y + height - 1. So, the intersect is exactly the pixel at 35, 45, with a size of 1x1 pixels. The calculation is therefore correct.

Comment: I don't understand your calculations: R1 goes from 25,43 to 36, 34 as width is 11 and height is 9. Moreover MS documentation is very clear: starting x and y are related to the upper-left corner. In my opinion that means you go right on the x axis and DOWN on the y axis. Otherwise starting y wouldn't be stated as the upper-left corner but the lower-left corner.

Comment: As in pretty much every modern graphics program, the Graphics context in .NET uses a coordinate system with 0,0 in the top left corner with the number increasing for x when going to the right, and increasing for y when going DOWN. Just try drawing a line from 10, 10 to 50, 50. You will see it sloping down ( \ ) and not up ( / ). Concerning my calculations: As I wrote, I stated the INCLUSIVE bounds. Take a rect starting at 10 with a width of 20. The highlighted pixels would be 10, 11, …, 28, 29. Pixel 30 would be the first pixel NOT highlighted. That's where the - 1 comes in.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Windows Coordinate System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/window-coordinate-system):

> The x-coordinates increase to the right; y-coordinates increase from
>   top to bottom.

Followed by:

> For screen coordinates, the origin is the upper-left corner of the
>   screen.

So the upper left corner of your screen is (0, 0), and the Y values **INCREASE** as you go **DOWN** the screen from the top to the bottom.

**Basically the Y-Axis has been flipped from what you're used to doing in standard math class graphing.**

Here I am displaying the coordinates not only using Left and Top, but also the [Right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.right?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Bottom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.bottom?view=netframework-4.7.2) properties:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("r1: ({0}, {1}) --> ({2}, {3})", r1.Left.ToString(), r1.Top.ToString(), r1.Right.ToString(), r1.Bottom.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("r2: ({0}, {1}) --> ({2}, {3})", r2.Left.ToString(), r2.Top.ToString(), r2.Right.ToString(), r2.Bottom.ToString()));
```

This results in the following output:

```
r1: (25, 43) --> (36, 52)
r2: (35, 45) --> (44, 46)
```

Hopefully that helps you understand what is going on.

Comment: No sir, you it's you who don't understand.I just asked Hans for a confirm. It seems MS is suggesting a coordinate system here that is not the Cartesian one, where values use to increase going up the y axis. Should anyone guess it ? In my opinion when something may be prone to misunderstanding, that should be well documented, especially in a technical paper. That was the only due answer.

Comment: It is well documented; and has been that way for **decades**...welcome to the world of programming!  Good luck.

Comment: Your post is based upon nothing, thus worthless. Here's the link to the official documentation to the class I asked about. Shouldn't I trust it ? Welcome to the world where what is worth saying must be supported by documents. Otherwise it's called "useless big mouthed fake news". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: My post already includes a link to the documentation I am referring to.  Each individual page does not necessarily give all the information you need for a topic,  you also need the background info. Get a book if you want the big picture laid out for you.  Furthermore, my post explains why your understanding of the rectangle is incorrect, and gives you code and documentation to demonstrate how it actually works.  Finally, the link **you** refer to does have this information as well.  In the Remarks,  follow the link to the Graphics class, then the link to Coordinate Systems and Transformations.